# React Native screen with presentation modal run function when slide down to close

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="MainScreen"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ModalScreen"
        component={ModalScreen}
        options={{
          presentation: 'modal',
          gestureEnabled: false,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default HomeStack
```

When from MainScreen navigate to ModalScreen, ModalScreen open like modal in front of MainScreen because of "presentation:'modal'". Because presentation is modal, user can slide down ModalScreen to close (gestureEnabled: true).
What I want to achieve? I want create a function that run when ModalScreen close by sliding down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to [focus](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#focus) event to detect when a modal is opened and closed.

```
const ModalScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // opened
    });
    return () => {
      // closed
      unsubscribe()
    };
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
...
  );
}
```